# Are HTTP cookies port specific?

Tags: security, http, cookies

I have two HTTP services running on one machine. I just want to know if they share their cookies or whether the browser distinguishes between the two server sockets.

Answer (score 462, accepted):

No, cookies do not provide isolation by port.

The current cookie specification is [RFC 6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265), which replaces [RFC 2109](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2109) and [RFC 2965](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2965) (both RFCs are now marked as "Historic") and formalizes the syntax for real-world usages of cookies.  It clearly states:

> 1. Introduction
>
> ...
>
> For historical reasons, cookies contain a number of security and privacy infelicities.  For example, a server can indicate that a given cookie is intended for "secure" connections, but the Secure attribute does not provide integrity in the presence of an active network attacker.  **Similarly, cookies for a given host are shared across all the ports on that host, even though the usual "same-origin policy" used by web browsers isolates content retrieved via different ports.**

And also:

> 8.5.  Weak Confidentiality
>
> **Cookies do not provide isolation by port**.  If a cookie is readable by a service running on one port, the cookie is also readable by a service running on another port of the same server.  If a cookie is writable by a service on one port, the cookie is also writable by a service running on another port of the same server.  For this reason, servers SHOULD NOT both run mutually distrusting services on different ports of the same host and use cookies to store security sensitive information.

Comment: `/etc/hosts` can be used to create more cookie domains for `127.0.0.1` than `localhost`

Comment: CORS changes the game rules: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46288437/set-cookies-for-cross-origin-requests With it you have server side: `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials`, `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`,  `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` + cookie setting `Secure`, `SameSite=None` and client side: `XMLHttpRequest.withCredentials` + ES6 fetch() `credentials: 'include'`

Comment: In case it helps anyone, I've written about this https://davidklempfner.medium.com/be-careful-running-multiple-localhost-apps-8e69e0a0293b?sk=bc0ce58ec76202ed8e52291425439b2b

Answer (score 153):

According to [RFC2965](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2965.txt) 3.3.1 (which might or might not be followed by browsers), unless the port is explicitly specified via the `port` parameter of the `Set-Cookie` header, cookies might or might not be sent to any port.

Google's [Browser Security Handbook](http://code.google.com/p/browsersec/wiki/Part2#Same-origin_policy_for_cookies) says: *by default, cookie scope is limited to all URLs on the current host name - and not bound to port or protocol information.* and some lines later *There is no way to limit cookies to a single DNS name only [...] likewise, there is no way to limit them to a specific port.* (Also, keep in mind, that IE does not factor port numbers into its same-origin policy *at all*.)

So it does not seem to be safe to rely on any well-defined behavior here.

Comment: [RFC 6265](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6265), which replaces RFC 2965, eliminates the `Port` parameter in the `Set-Cookie` header (because almost nobody actually used it in practice), and makes it very explicit that cookies on the same host ARE NOT distinquishable by ports anymore.

Comment: IE 9 won't even send the cookie back on subsequent requests if the domain has a port in it

Comment: Is there any browser that is still considering port in its cookies' SOP?

Comment: Chrome won't even set the cookie if it has the domain has a port in it.

Answer (score 120):

This is a really old question but I thought I would add a workaround I used.

I have two services running on my laptop (one on port 3000 and the other on 4000).
When I would jump between (`http://localhost:3000` and `http://localhost:4000`), Chrome would pass in the same cookie, each service would not understand the cookie and generate a new one.

I found that if I accessed `http://localhost:3000` and `http://127.0.0.1:4000`, the problem went away since Chrome kept a cookie for localhost and one for 127.0.0.1.

Again, no one may care at this point but it was easy and helpful to my situation.

Comment: Yes, because cookies are associated with host/domain names, so a cookie on `localhost` cannot by shared with `127.0.0.1` and vice versa.  But cookies on the same host/domain, regardless of port, are sharable.

Comment: This probably works only in Chrome, as most other browsers don't send cookies to "localhost" (=a string without two dots)

Comment: Of course they do. I (and probably million other developers) use localhost for testing all the time. Unless the added port makes a difference: http://localhost:8080/

Comment: Also, you can use 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.2, 127.0.0.3 etc... they all mean localhost.

Comment: If you're willing to edit your hosts file (/etc/hosts on Unix) you can have as many meaningful names as you like for localhost.

Comment: @DavidBalažic No, "localhost" means 127.0.0.1. 127.0.0.2 usually doesn't have a name. These addresses are distinct unicast addresses and treated just as any different unicast addresses by the TCP protocol, but they are all local.

Comment: @SilasS.Brown Please don't say "for localhost". "localhost" is the name associated with a particular IP address. Say "the local host".

Comment: Also it can be handy to use subdomains like http://foo.localhost:3000 and http://bar.localhost:4000

Comment: You can set local domains of your choosing that alias to 0.0.0.0, 127.0.0.1, etc. in the /etc/hosts file. You're not confined to localhost. The syntax is pretty straight forward `<ip> <domain_alias1> <domain_alias2> ...` e.g. `127.0.0.1 api.foo.bar spa.foo.bar admin.foo.bar`.

Answer (score 23):

This is a big gray area in cookie SOP (Same Origin Policy).

Theoretically, you can specify port number in the domain and the cookie will not be shared. In practice, this doesn't work with several browsers and you will run into other issues. So this is only feasible if your sites are not for general public and you can control what browsers to use.

The better approach is to get 2 domain names for the same IP and not relying on port numbers for cookies.

Comment: It is not a gray area anymore. [RFC 6265](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6265), which is the current cookie standard, eliminates any confusion about it by simply eliminating the ability to separate cookies on the same host using different ports.

Answer (score 20):

An alternative way to go around the problem, is to make the name of the session cookie be port related. For example:

- **mysession8080** for the server running on port 8080
- **mysession8000** for the server running on port 8000

Your code could access the webserver configuration to find out which port your server uses, and name the cookie accordingly.

Keep in mind that your application will receive both cookies, and you need to request the one that corresponds to your port.

There is no need to have the exact port number in the cookie name, but this is more convenient.

In general, the cookie name could encode any other parameter specific to the server instance you use, so it can be decoded by the right context.

Comment: This works for mutually trusting web services sharing the host name on different port numbers.   But all host-related cookies will be sent to all web services of that host regardless of their names. If the host allows malicious unprivileged operators run web services on separate port numbers, the operators can abuse browsers of customers of the original web service into sending all host-related cookies, including the secret ones, to the malicious web service that shares the host.

Answer (score 10):

In IE 8, cookies (verified only against localhost) are shared between ports. In FF 10, they are not.

I've posted this answer so that readers will have at least one concrete option for testing each scenario.

Answer (score 6):

I was experiencing a similar problem running (and trying to debug) two different Django applications on the same machine.

I was running them with these commands:

```
./manage.py runserver 8000
./manage.py runserver 8001
```

When I did login in the first one and then in the second one I always got logged out the first one and viceversa.

I added this on my **/etc/hosts**

```
127.0.0.1    app1
127.0.0.1    app2
```

Then I started the two apps with these commands:

```
./manage.py runserver app1:8000
./manage.py runserver app2:8001
```

Problem solved :)

Comment: you can probably use `127.0.0.1:8000` for one, `localhost:8000` for a second, and possibly `::1:8000` (maybe `[::1]:8080`) for a third without ever having to touch the hosts file.

Comment: you can put it into one line: ```::1 app1 app2 app3 app4 app5 appN```

Answer (score -1):

It's optional.

The port may be specified so cookies can be port specific. It's not necessary, the web server / application must care of this.

Source: [German Wikipedia article](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP-Cookie), [RFC2109](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2109/rfc2109), Chapter 4.3.1

Comment: [Sounds like it's more complicated than this in real life.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612177/are-http-cookies-port-specific/4212964#4212964)