# PHP-SDK getUser() always 0 / not authenticated

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk, codeigniter-2, csrf

I'm using the A3M CodeIgniter library, with updated FB PHP-SDK 3.2.

I'm forced into updating from 2.x as Facebook retired their 'legacy' connection method the other day, and that's what the a3m framework used.  So I updated to the SDK, and now cannot get the connect process working for a number of reasons:

1. Infinite redirect of `getLoginUrl()`
2. `CSRF state token does not match one provided` errors (not using `getLoginUrl()` if I get a user).
3. User is ALWAYS `0`, even tho I am logged in on FB.

I am really not sure what to do at this point.

My thoughts:

- CodeIgniter could be stripping the response `code` / `state` ? Not sure
- Authentication is failing / no errors being dropped other than CSRF error (not from CI!)
- Many issues reported (especially on SO) with this infinite redirect from FB
- Many issues reported on CSRF issue with PHP SDK.

**REF:**
https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk - FB SDK
https://github.com/pengkong/A3M-for-CodeIgniter-2.0 - A3M framework (which I am part of managing).

Ideas?

Comment: I've experienced similar problems with the FB PHP SDK. One thing I always forget to check is that sandbox mode is enabled for local testing. Also, Chrome doesn't set domain cookies for localhost, which could cause issues (http://stackoverflow.com/a/8225269/222622)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is Facebook PHP SDK getUser always returning 0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6790272/why-is-facebook-php-sdk-getuser-always-returning-0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Destroy the session with `$facebook->destroySession()` for getting user 0.

Regarding 2 Facebook SDK code has a bug when checking against tokens twice in the same handler.

I edited the getCode function of `facebook.php` like this:

```
protected function getCode() {
    if (!isset($_REQUEST['code']) || !isset($_REQUEST['state']) || $this->state === null) {
      return false;
    }
    if ($this->state === $_REQUEST['state']) {
        // CSRF state has done its job, so clear it
        $this->state = null;
        $this->clearPersistentData('state');
        return $_REQUEST['code'];
    }
    self::errorLog('CSRF state token does not match one provided.');

    return false;
}
```

to be more clear and does not state invalid token if called twice.

To be clear the function can be called twice on the same url handler if eg:

`$facebook->getUser();` and then in the same handler `$facebook->getLogoutUrl()` then the `getCode()` is called twice thus resulting into and invalid error message

Comment: thanks, I previously solved this with a patch similar to what you proposed, marking as answer as it was the solution I used before.

Comment: @Jakub it's a pity that FBSDK for php has so many bugs. Really hard to get things solved.

Comment: @Jakub there is also a pull request https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/pull/122

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt in modules/account/helper with the one from https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/tree/master/src