# Set cookie in ApiController doesn't work in chrome

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, asp.net-web-api, setcookie

I have an `ApiController` in which I set a `tokenId` as cookie using this code:

```
var cookie = new HttpCookie("TokenId", tokenId)
                         {
                             Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
                             Domain = this.Request.RequestUri.Host,
                             Path = "/"
                         };

HttpContext.Current.Response.SetCookie(cookie);
```

Using `Firefox` it's working and firebug shows the received cookie. But `Chrome` doesn't show the cookie in the debugger. And on the further `HttpRequest`s it doesn't send the cookie

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chrome doesn't create cookie for domain=localhost in broken https](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8134384/chrome-doesnt-create-cookie-for-domain-localhost-in-broken-https)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems `Chrome` can not store cookies with domain `localhost`. So while developing a website you can't store cookies!

I've found out this problem via another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8134384/chrome-doesnt-create-cookie-for-domain-localhost-in-broken-https):

This problem is also addressed at [here](http://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/group/chromium-bugs/browse_thread/thread/e0714b0e1bef5ec7?pli=1) which caused some developers to leave chrome and migrate to Firefox!