# How to see cookies with Google Chrome Inspector?

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-chrome-devtools, web-inspector

I am using Google Chrome Web Inspector to debug a web page.

In tab network, I am able to see a call to a Server API and detect Request Cookies and Response Cookies for that URL, os I suppose a cookies has been saved in the browser, but if I visit the Resource section under Cookies I can see any... this site has no cookies

Could you provide me more information?

Comment: Are you saying that the site has cookies but Inspector isn't showing them?

Comment: Yes, I cannot see it under the inspector in the resource tab.

Comment: Did you click the arrow on the left?

Comment: Thanks for your link, yes I tried no success. Help me to understand.. Could you confirm when using Resource/Cookies I should be able to see all the cookies for my website...correct? Even if the page I am testing is on LocalHost?

Comment: Could be a similar problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7346919/chrome-localhost-cookie-not-being-set ??

Comment: "Resources/Cookies" only appears to show the cookies that are available at the current URL / the current request (basically what is in the HTTP request header). If a cookie is only available on a different _path_ then it will not be shown here. If you need to see _all cookies on the domain_ then you need to open Settings > Content Settings > All cookies and site data...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved replacing

```
http://localhost:8888/
```

with

```
http://127.0.0.1:8888/
```

now I am able to set cookies for my webpage o my local dev environment.

This question help me to resolve the problem
[Chrome localhost cookie not being set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7346919/chrome-localhost-cookie-not-being-set)

Answer (score 1):

The root issue for why a cookie is showing in 127.0.0.1 and not localhost has to do with the domain of the cookie. When a cookie is set, one sets the domain of the cookie and I suspect the server is setting the domain for 127.0.0.1 and not localhost