# JavaScript Cookie not writing based on URL Attributes

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I wrote a script that creates a cookie, and sets the name and value based on form data *?docname=*,

the *getValue* comes from this script that gets the form data:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!-- hide from old browsers

function getValue(varname)
{
  // First, we load the URL into a variable
  var url = window.location.href.replace(new RegExp( "\\+", "g" ), "%20" )

  // Next, split the url by the ?
  var qparts = url.split("?");

  // Check that there is a querystring, return "" if not
  if (qparts.length == 0)
  {
    return "";
  }

  // Then find the querystring, everything after the ?
  var query = qparts[1];

  // Split the query string into variables (separates by &s)
  var vars = query.split("&");

  // Initialize the value with "" as default
  var value = "";

  // Iterate through vars, checking each one for varname
  for (i=0;i<vars.length;i++)
  {
    // Split the variable by =, which splits name and value
    var parts = vars[i].split("=");

    // Check if the correct variable
    if (parts[0] == varname)
    {
      // Load value into variable
      value = parts[1];

      // End the loop
      break;
    }
  }

  // Convert escape code
  value = unescape(value);

  // Convert "+"s to " "s
  value.replace("+"," ");

  // Return the value
  return value;
}

// end hide -->
</script>

<script>
function saveDoc()
{
var docname= getValue("docname"); // these go off another script to get form data
var save = getValue("save");
var url = window.location.href;
}
if (docname != '') {
setCookie(docname,url,730);
}
else {
 // Nothing else to do
}
</script>
```

It is supposed to be created when the user clicks this link:

```
<a href="#" onclick="saveDoc()" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" id="save" title="" data-original-title="Save"><i class="icon-folder-open"></i></button>
```

I ran an error script with the help of an answer and it said Uncaught referenceError setCookie not defined.

But when a script on another page checks for it, its not there.

Why isn't it creating the cookie?

Like this right? {

```
var docname= getValue("docname"); // these go off another script to get form data
    var save = getValue("save");
    var url = window.location.href;
}
function setCookie(name, value, days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
}
function saveDoc() {
    if (docname != '') {
        setCookie(docname,url,730);
    }
    else {
     // Nothing else to do
    }
}
// Helps to find errors if they exist
window.onerror = function(errorMessage, url, line) {
    var errorText = 'message: ' + errorMessage + '\nurl: ' + url + '\nline: ' + line;
    alert(errorText);
}
```

Comment: Use some tool like firebug. Extract and post the http request for cookie. Check if the cookie is created or not in your browser.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Ankit, But that's not what I'm looking for. Thanks so much though.

Comment: Can we see `setCookie` function? Is it really called when button clicked (if yes, then some logs for **docname**, **url**)?

Comment: yeah @bob I'll add some to my post

Comment: If it's your actual code, accidentally `if/else` statement is out of `saveDoc` function.

Comment: @bob can you explain more about that? maybe a sample? cause I'm not sure what you mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `saveDoc` function must be like that including `if` statement:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function saveDoc() {
    var docname= getValue("docname"); // these go off another script to get form data
    var save = getValue("save");
    var url = window.location.href;
    if (docname != '') {
        setCookie(docname,url,730);
    }
    else {
     // Nothing else to do
    }
}
// Helps to find errors if they exist
window.onerror = function(errorMessage, url, line) {
    var errorText = 'message: ' + errorMessage + '\nurl: ' + url + '\nline: ' + line;
    alert(errorText);
}
</script>
```

**Edit**

Explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825683/how-do-i-create-and-read-a-value-from-cookie) more about setting cookie. And your `setCookie` function should be defined until `saveDoc` function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function setCookie(name, value, days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
}
function saveDoc() {
    // save your doc here
}
</script>
```

Comment: The Error says Uncaught ReferenceError, setCookie is not defined.

Comment: Thanks for the error reporter though, makes it so my users know whether or not it worked, once it does work.

Comment: @brandonjordan I edited my answer, it should solve `not defined` issue.

Comment: IT WORKED! Thanks so much @bob! if there's anything you need so far as coding, etc. goes let me know!

Comment: Like in the last script I just updated In The post? cause it only records this much of the url _http://nsc-component.webs.com/Office/Editor/new-doc.html?docname_ It creates the cookie though

Comment: if that can be solved it should completely fix the problem, the problem was if need to have form data _?docname_, and it keeps cutting it off, If you don't know i'll see what I can do, thanks for all of your help @bob

Answer (score 0):

What browser are you using?  Note that developing with cookies in can be a little tricky because some browsers won't let you [set cookies from localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7346919/chrome-localhost-cookie-not-being-set).  Instead, you'll need to test from 127.0.0.1.

Otherwise, its hard to tell what's going on without being able to see the code in your function calls...

Comment: I'm using Chrome 28.0.1501.0 canary