# Not able to set cookie from action

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies, asp.net-web-api

I have **ASP.NET MVC** application hosted along with **ASP.NET WebApi** application at `localhost` and `localhost/api` and I wan't to set a cookie when one action of **ASP.NET WebApi** called.

I tried to set my cookie like that:

```
response.Headers.AddCookies(new[]
                                        {
                                            new CookieHeaderValue("test", "asd")
                                            {
                                                Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
                                                Domain = Request.RequestUri.Host,
                                                Path = "/",
                                                HttpOnly = false
                                            }
                                        });
```

I got that in response headers:

```
Set-Cookie:test=asd; expires=Thu, 30 Oct 2014 09:53:35 GMT; domain=localhost; path=/
```

But that cookie is not creating for some reason.

Just for testing purposes I tried to set cookie from **ASP.NET MVC** application like that:

```
HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("test", "asd")
            {
                Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
                Domain = HttpContext.Request.Url.Host,
                Path = "/",
                HttpOnly = false
            });
```

Response headers contain:

```
Set-Cookie:test=asd; domain=localhost; expires=Thu, 30-Oct-2014 09:56:08 GMT; path=/
```

But still I can't see that cookie. What I am doing wrong how it could be so these headers are ignored? However, other cookies work fine (e.g. .ASPXAUTH).

Comment: What do you mean by "can't see that cookie"? Where are you looking?

Comment: @SveinFidjestøl document.cookie and at Resources tab in Chrome dev tools

Comment: You can't set cookies on localhost, at least not with Chrome. You need at least a two part name. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7346919/chrome-localhost-cookie-not-being-set

Comment: @SveinFidjestøl **Domain = null** did a trick, thanks a lot. Can you format it as an answer please?

Comment: Sure thing, I have entered my answer below

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't set cookies on localhost, at least not with Chrome.

You need at least a two part name, e.g. mytestsite.local, or you need to set

```
Domain = null
```

in the C# code.