# Spring Boot with Angular 7 frontend - Prevent accessing site from not-logged-in users

Tags: java, angular, spring, spring-boot, authentication

I'd like to prevent people from accessing my application (Angular 7 frontend, Spring Boot backend) when they are not logged in using `Spring-Boot-Security`. I authenticate my user via `ldap` and would like to set roles based on database entries, but let's get to this step by step. So what I did now is replacing the default `Spring-Boot-Security`-login (via the generated password) with my `ldap`-configuration (but still using the default login-page). I got the following code for that:

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .antMatcher("/login")
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
            .and()
            .httpBasic();
        http.formLogin().defaultSuccessUrl("/", true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() {
        return new ProviderManager(Arrays.asList(activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider()));
    }
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider() {
        ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider provider = new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider(AD_DOMAIN, AD_URL);
        provider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
        provider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);
        return provider;
    }
```

Now by default when including the `spring-boot-starter-security` artifact, everyone is redirected to the `/login`-page when trying to access any page. Sadly since I overwrote that config with my own that is not the case any more. How can I let spring do this again (also with the frontend-pages, which were prevented from accessing too)?

Comment: It's not clear what is your question. Do you want to redirect unauthenticated users to another url, different from `/login`? Or is your problem that authenticated users are redirected to `/login`?

Comment: @naXa I would like to have people redirected to `/login` when they try to access any page but did not already authenticate via `/login`. Yet, I just found out about what I did wrong. I specified the `antMatcher` which seems to override the `httpSecurity`-options for this and prevented spring-boot from redirecting every time. Removing that line and inserting `.formLogin().and()` right before `httpBasic()` did the trick

Comment: Good news:) If you managed to solve your question yourself, please take some time to post an answer. You can then accept it in 2 days. This way you share the knowledge with others and officially mark this question as resolved.

Comment: Also, do you think your question is similar to this existing question? 
[Spring Security keeps redirecting me to login page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41827388/1429387)