# localhost redirects to a different page

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redirect, localhost

I am experiencing a problem with my Spring Boot project. When I run the application and go to http://localhost:8086/ it redirects to http://localhost:8086/login which is not the page I want.

This is the content of my **application.properties** file

```
#Database
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_name
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.platform=mysql
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

#Html
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/public/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.html

#Server
server.port=8086
```

I have also added this class which is supposed to open the index.html file found in the **/public/** folder as specified in the properties above

```
public class WebAppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("forward:/index.html");
    }

}
```

Is there something that I am doing wrong or should I log in first in the page that it redirects to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully [Here you can find your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41848600/266636), basically it's in the [configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#authorize-requests)