# How to ensure cookies are sent back to server from any request in node.js/express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies, session-cookies

In my node.js express app, I set a cookie on a request like this

```
            res.cookie('token', access.token, {
                //secure: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "development",
                maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
                httpOnly: true // prevent cross-site scripting attacks (XSS) attacks
            });
```

Then in dev tools in the network tab, if I click the request, I can see the cookies tab and see the value there.

However if I go to the application tab and click on cookies, I don't see my cookie there. As well if I keep making any more requests, the `cookie-parser` module is not seeing the cookie as well.

How can I ensure the cookie above gets sent back to the server for all requests?

[image]

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Remove `httpOnly` in your options and see if it changes anything. Depending on the browser some may not display HTTPOnly cookies (non-accessible by JavaScript) in the cookie area...

Comment: Could we see the full HTTP response of the server response which sets the cookie?

Comment: I added the pics

Comment: I also tried with httponly as false

Comment: Can be related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7346919/chrome-localhost-cookie-not-being-set)

Comment: It's because you are using a secure flag with a `http` connection. Secure cookies are only being set for `https`.