# Cookies on localhost not being set... what to do?

Tags: cookies, browser, cors, samesite

I have a frontend running on `http://localhost:5173` and a backend running on `http://localhost:3000`. I just can't test cookies sent by the backend anymore... the `POST` response looks like this:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:5173
Vary: Origin
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 118
ETag: W/"76-RnnHeJL+YLKFl67NESlMHiQ6x/0"
Set-Cookie: connect.sid=MYSECRETCOOKIE_123455; Path=/; Expires=Mon, 19 Feb 2024 00:50:59 GMT; HttpOnly; SameSite=None
```

I know this won't work on Chrome, because `SameSite=None` and `Secure!=true` but it used to be that on Firefox I could disable the [Cookies without SameSite must be secure option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60977857/2076973).

However, on Firefox Mac build 122.0.1, **this is still not setting the cookie.**

Is there any alternative on how to test cookies with different URLs on local deployments?

Comment: _Generate your own certificate, either self-signed or signed by a local root, and trust it in your operating system’s trust store. Then use that certificate in your local web server._ Source: https://letsencrypt.org/docs/certificates-for-localhost/

Comment: @jub0bs I added https to both frontend and backend, etc, still doesn’t work.

Comment: Have you added the `Secure` attribute?

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that, in this specific case, `SameSite` (and, therefore, `Secure` too) can be omitted, because `http://localhost:5173` and `http://localhost:3000` happen to be [_same-site_](https://site-and-origin.securitum.com/).

Comment: @jub0bs I added `SameSite=None; Secure`, with `https`, still didn't work. I could try removing them, but I have little hope

Comment: Nope. `SameSite: None; HttpOnly; Secure` over `https` does not work either. Nothing works, even on Firefox. Cross-site cookies are apparently dead

Comment: No need to give way to despair. Everything has an explanation. You should tell us more about the client code; share it in your question if you can.