# Ruby on rails - Cookies not saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies

I try to realize shopping cart, and i wrote this code:

```
if cookies[:shopping_cart]
  Cart.find(cookies[:shopping_cart][:value])
else
  cookies[:test] = 'tt'
  cart = Cart.create

  cookies[:shopping_cart] = {
  :value => cart.id,
  :expires => 1.week.from_now.utc,
  :path => '/',
  :domain => 'localhost:3000'
  }
end
```

But every time i have cookies[:shopping_cart] nil, and every time my "code" try to create new cookies[:shopping_cart].

cookies[:test] also equal nil every time.

that suggest?

Comment: are you sure, this code is ever called?

Comment: i check it by loggers and i debug it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i remove

```
:path => '/',
:domain => 'localhost:3000'
```

and it worked now!!

Answer (score 0):

Removing the port number from domain name, would work as the cookie won't consider the port as [it stores the same cookie for the any port of the same server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612177/are-http-cookies-port-specific)([RFC6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265))

```
:domain => 'localhost'
```