# Django Socketio Nginx proxy & session cookie issue

Tags: django, http, cookies, nginx, websocket

I have followed this tutorial: http://www.stephendiehl.com/?p=309 describing how to run a gevent pywsgi server serving Django with socketio behind a nginx front-end.

As this tutorial says, Nginx doesn't support websocket unless using a tcp proxy module. This proxy module doesn't support the use of the same port for socketio and classic serving, from what I understood the configuration look like that:

nginx listen on port 80

nginx tcp proxy listen  on port 7000

Everything is forwarded to port 8000

**Problem:** the resulting socketio request doesn't include the django cookie containing the session id so I have no information on the requesting user in my django view.

I guess it's caused by the fact that the request is made to another port (7000) causing the browser to identify the request as cross-domain ?

What would be the cleanest way to include the django cookie into the request ?

Answer (score 1):

Most answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612177/are-http-cookies-port-specific) seem to indicate that port doesn't matter.

Also checked and supposedly WebSockets is regarded as HTTP, so HTTPOnly cookies should still be sent.

SocketIO seems to be using a custom Session manager to track users. Maybe try and link that up?

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. I do believe now that it's more about the protocol than the port (like you just said). I wasn't successful at linking the two session so I fall back to long polling.