# Removing cookies from different ports

Tags: php, cookies, port

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are HTTP cookies port specific?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612177/are-http-cookies-port-specific)

I have two servers with a different port. Let's say:

1. `http://example.com`
2. `http://example.com:8080`

I **create** a cookie in `http://example.com:8080` and **cannot delete** that cookie from  `http://example.com/signout.php`

Also one thing more:

I had that same issue before with http and https.
In that same url (`http://example.com/signout.php`) the cookie was successfully deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not cookies are bound to a particular port seems to be somwhat undefined. Take a look at the following related question:

[Are HTTP cookies port specific?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612177/are-http-cookies-port-specific)

So it sounds like it may vary and it isn't safe to rely on the assumption you'll be able to delete cookies across ports.

Comment: When you get the rep, this should have been a close-as-dupe vote, not an answer, FWIW.

Comment: Hi Charles, thanks for the advice I didn't know if it was close enough to be treated as a dupe. But you're right I don't have enough rep to do it.

Comment: It's actually kind of pushing it.  The answer is there, but in a roundabout way.