# Do applications with spring security share SecurityContextHolder among them

Tags: java, session, spring-security, httpsession

I have two different applications, say `A` and . Both are using Spring Security with the same configuration. Here is my situation:

I log into my `A` application. Everything works fine. But when I log into my `B` application (it has the same IP but different PORT) in another tab in the same browser, I see these lines (below) and I am thrown away from `A` application, which means I am no longer authenticated in it.

> DEBUG 2013-05-20 13:42:43,969 [http-8080-2] org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain : /webapp/backoffice/index.jsp at position 2 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
>
> DEBUG 2013-05-20 13:42:43,969 [http-8080-2] org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No HttpSession currently exists
>
> DEBUG 2013-05-20 13:42:43,969 [http-8080-2] org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.

1. I am using `HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository` as **SecurityContextRepository**.
2. I have enabled **SessionMigration** for security purposes.
3. I am using **ConcurrentSessionFilter**, to prevent someone being logged in via two or more devices.

But I am not getting why logging in my `B` application, removes the HttpSession from `A` application? (Or maybe some other things are happening)

I want to know whether these applications, share something in common within the browser.

---

As I am asked about their IP/PORT, you should know that their IPs are the same (both localhost) but they have different ports.
`A)` *localhost:8080/dtts/backoffice*
`B)` *localhost:8081/dtts/backoffice*

---

**SOLVED**
The problem was that for every `URL/Path` there will be a unique `JSESSIONID`. Both of my applications use `URL:localhost` and `Path:dtts`. That's why the second `JSESSIONID` replaces the first one.

Comment: Are both the IP address *and* the port different for each application? I'd recommend using a tool like Fiddler to analyse the traffic going back and forward to each web application, especially the contents of the JSESSIONID cookies.

Comment: Please provide URLs of A and B

Comment: Updated the answer. Their IPs are the same (both are `localhost`) but they have different ports (`A` uses 8080, and `B` uses 8081)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cookie from application B is overwriting the cookie stored in the browser for application A, because both cookies are from the same server i.e. 'localhost', and both cookies have the name, i.e. 'JSESSIONID'.

Cookies are not port specific. This is discussed in this question: [Are HTTP cookies port specific?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612177/are-http-cookies-port-specific)

I believe your options are:

- Use a different IP or server name to access each application (e.g.
  localhost and 127.0.0.1, or applicationA.mydomain.com and applicationB.mydomain.com)
- Use a different name for the session
  cookie in the container that each application is running in

Comment: That sounds logical! How can I have different session cookie names for these applications?

Comment: If using tomcat 7, its the sessionCookieName attribute in Context.XML. see docs here: http://tomcat.apache.org/migration-7.html#Session_manager_configuration

Comment: I have read the document, and it says it is not a good idea to change the 'JSESSIONID` name to anything else, as the Servlet uses this name by default.

Comment: Yeah, the first option is certainly the nicer way to go about fixing this, if it's possible in your deployment model.

Comment: It turned out to be path-specific, and not related to port. So there will be a unique `JSESSIONID` for every `URL/Path`. My problem was that two applications used the same `Path` as well.

Comment: Cool, thanks for update. I can't recommend Fiddler enough for this kind of problem btw. Cheers.