# How to change contex path of a web application using redirection or something like this

Tags: jakarta-ee, url-rewriting, contextpath

I have two web applications, `A` and `B`. The URL for these applications are as follows:
`A` uses `localhost:8080/dx/dx/backoffice`
`B` uses `localhost:8081/dx/dx/customer`

As I have found that [cookies are **Path-Specific**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16646528/do-applications-with-spring-security-share-securitycontextholder-among-them), I need to somehow change the context-path of these two applications, to avoid overwriting of cookies.

I need something like this:
I enter `localhost:8080/admin` and it should be redirected to `localhost:8080/dx/dx/backoffice`. I also need to keep the URL unchanged. Because if it is changed explicitly, it is exactly the same as writing the old URL, which does not help at all.

I came about using URL-Rewriting, but there were two problems:
1. Only those parts of URL were being replaced which came after the project name!
2. The URL explicitly changed, which makes this whole effort useless.

Is there a way to do something like this?