# HttpClient does not send cookies from CookieContainer

Tags: asp.net, cookies, asp.net-web-api

I'm developing a ASP WebAPI (ASP MVC 4) application with a WPF (.NET 4.0) client, using Visual Studio 2012. The client needs to login to the server. I use FormsAuthentication with an authentication cookie to login. The login already works fine in ASP MVC.

The problem is that, although the login is sucessfully executed on the server and the cookie is sent back to the client, the cookie is not sent in subsequent calls to the server, even though the `CookieContainer` is reused with the auth cookie set.

Here is a simplified version of the code:

**CLIENT**

```
public async Task<UserProfile> Login(string userName, string password, bool rememberMe)
{           
    using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler() { CookieContainer = this.cookieContainer })
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler))
    {
        httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:50000/");

        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
            new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        var result = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("api/auth/login", new
        {
            username = userName,
            password = password,
            rememberMe = rememberMe
        });

        result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        var userProfile = await result.Content.ReadAsAsync<UserProfile>();

        if (userProfile == null)
            throw new UnauthorizedAccessException();

        return userProfile;
    }
}

public async Task<ExamSubmissionResponse> PostItem(Item item)
{
    using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler() { CookieContainer = this.cookieContainer })
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler))
    {
        httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:50000/");

        var result = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("api/Items/", item);
    }
}
```

**SERVER**

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Login(LoginModel model)
{
    if (this.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
    {
        // Get user data from database

        string userData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userModel);

        var authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
            1,
            model.UserName,
            DateTime.Now,
            DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10 * 15),
            model.RememberMe,
            userData
        );              

        string ticket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);
        var cookie = new CookieHeaderValue(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, ticket);
        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, userModel);
        response.Headers.AddCookies(new CookieHeaderValue[] { cookie });

        return response;
    }
    return null;
}
```

First I debugged the problem using Fiddler2 (I used the base address as "`http://localhost.fiddler:50000/`" to view local traffic). Then I suspected that fiddler might be interfering, so I just debugged with Visual Studio 2012.

What I have tried and verified:

- The server is reached by the Login method
- The user is sucessfully authenticated with the data sent from the client
- The cookie is set on the server
- The cookie is in the response (verified with fiddler)
- The cookie is in the CookieContainer after the operation. There is a strange thing here: **the domain of the cookie in the container is set as "localhost"** (verified with VS2012 debugger). **Shouldn't it be "`http://localhost:50000`"** ? When I try to get the cookies of the container using `cookieContainer.GetCookies(new Uri("http://localhost:50000"))` it returns nothing. When I try it using `cookieContainer.GetCookies(new Uri("localhost"))` it gives me an invalid Uri error. Not sure what's going on here.
- The cookie is in the container just before the `PostItem` request is made. The container is correctly set in the HttpClient when the statement `httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync` is reached.
- The cookie is not sent to the server (I checked it with fiddler and in the `Application_PostAuthenticateRequest` method in the Global.asax.cs, verifying `this.Request.Cookies`)

I suspect the cookie is not being sent due to a domain mismatch in the `CookieContainer`, but why the domain is not set as it should in the `CookieContainer` in the first place?

Comment: Can you show what the cookie looks like in from fiddler?  'new Uri("localhost")' is not valid because you are specifying a relative URI but not saying it is relative.  Try new Uri("http://localhost").

Comment: Also, you really should not be recreating the HttpClient on each request.  Store it as a field and re-use the same instance.

Comment: Try explicitly setting the cookie path to "/" in the web.api login controller before returning the response. I have not tested this, but it may be that if you add the cookie without setting the path, it will default to the path of the current request. If that is the case it would explain why the cookie is not sent in the following request which is to a different path.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem is that you are not setting any path on the cookie that you send back from your Web Api controller.

There are two things that control where cookies are sent:

1. The domain of the cookie
2. The path of the cookie

Regarding the domain, the consensus seems to be that the port number should no longer (but still might) be a factor in evaluating the cookie domain. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612177/are-http-cookies-port-specific) for more info about how port number affects the domain.

About the path: Cookies are associated with a specific path in their domain. In your case, the Web Api is sending a cookie without specifying it's path. By default the cookie will then be associated with the path of the request/response where the cookie was created.

In your case the cookie will have the path `api/auth/login`. This means the the cookie will be sent to *child paths* (for lack of a better term) of this path but not to *parent* or *sibling* paths.

To test this, try:

```
cookieContainer.GetCookies(new Uri("http://localhost/api/auth/login")
```

This should give you the cookie. So should this:

```
cookieContainer.GetCookies(new Uri("http://localhost/api/auth/login/foo/bar")
```

These on the other hand will not find the cookie:

```
cookieContainer.GetCookies(new Uri("http://localhost/")
cookieContainer.GetCookies(new Uri("http://localhost/api/")
cookieContainer.GetCookies(new Uri("http://localhost/api/auth/")
cookieContainer.GetCookies(new Uri("http://localhost/api/auth/foo")
cookieContainer.GetCookies(new Uri("http://localhost/api/Items/")
```

To fix the issue, simply add the path "/" (or perhaps "/api") to the cookie before sending the resonse:

```
...
string ticket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);
var cookie = new CookieHeaderValue(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, ticket);
cookie.Path = "/";
var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, userModel);
response.Headers.AddCookies(new CookieHeaderValue[] { cookie });
...
```

Comment: Setting "cookie.Path" to "/" did the job. Thank you!