# AngularJS - Does $resource requests send cookies automatically?

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource, angular-cookies

I am using a $resource in my angularJS app. Does it send automatically my cookies? I am doing requests on the same domain.

Answer (score 4):

Browser will always send a cookie along with the request (no matter if it's an XHR request or not) as long as all assumptions are met (same domain, matching path, matching port, same protocol, not expired, etc.).

Since `$resource` service is just a simple Ajax wrapper your cookies will/should be sent (if everything's in place).

Comment: What if it's a different domain?

Answer (score 3):

No. But if you want to send cookies, then you can try [$cookies](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies.%24cookies) service to get the cookie and send with API either in the payload or included in the header.

You can also set the cookie in a default header (with `$cookies` service injected) so you don't have to specify it in all API calls.

```
var cookie = $cookies.myCookie; // suppose you already set $cookies.myCookie= 'xxx';
$http.defaults.headers.post.Cookies = cookie;
```

Comment: How can handle the post back? All my requests are going through the $resource object.

Comment: @poiuytrez Ever find an answer?  I want to mass assign 10 resources and would benefit from your learning.

Answer (score 1):

Note that running different applications on the same domain but on **different ports** might also be a reason for why cookies are not sent.

Cookies should not be port specific (regarding SOP), but CORS definitely is. Also see [Are HTTP cookies port specific?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612177/are-http-cookies-port-specific)

In my experience no current Browser (FF 47, Chrome 51, IE11) sends cookies for example from localhost:3000 to localhost:8080 in a XHR request.