# CORS issue angularjs and spring security

Tags: angularjs, spring, cors

I have an application that will be deployed at two places. There would be one master and one slave. I have a requirement that some of the requests should be satisfied by slave and others by master.

For this, I am sending login request to master on successful login to slave. I am able to achieve this.

My problem is, when i try to access any resource from master(request a resource from master originating from slave) after logging in, It is giving unauthorized(401) error.

Login controller:

```
  $http.post('j_spring_security_check', payload, config).success(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR, dataType) {
                    if ($scope.rememberme) {
                        var user = {
                            username: $scope.username,
                            password: $rootScope.encryptPass($scope.password, true),
                            rememberme: $scope.rememberme
                        };
                        localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
                    } else {
                        localStorage.removeItem('user');
                    }
                    $rootScope.pingServer();
                    $rootScope.retrieveNotificationCount();
                    $http.post('http://localhost:9090/context/j_spring_security_check',payload, config).success(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR, dataType) {

                        $rootScope.pingServer();
                    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

                    });
                });
```

app.js

```
rootapp.config(['$httpProvider', function(httpProvider) {
            httpProvider.interceptors.push(['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
                    return {
                        request: function(config) {
                            config.headers = config.headers||{};
                            config.headers['withCredentials'] = true;
                            config.headers['useXDomain'] = true;
                            return config;
                        }
                    }
                }]);
```

My server has a filter

```
@Singleton
public class ResponseCorsFilter implements Filter {
 @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        if (servletResponse instanceof HttpServletResponse) {
            if (request.getMethod().equals("OPTION") || request.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS")) {
                System.out.println("In Options");
                if (request.getServletPath().equals("/j_spring_security_check")) {
                    System.out.println("request path match");
                    alteredResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
                    addHeadersFor200Response(alteredResponse);
                    return;
                }
            }

            addHeadersFor200Response(alteredResponse);
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    }

    private void addHeadersFor200Response(HttpServletResponse response) {
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "ACL, CANCELUPLOAD, CHECKIN, CHECKOUT, COPY, DELETE, GET, HEAD, LOCK, MKCALENDAR, MKCOL, MOVE, OPTIONS, POST, PROPFIND, PROPPATCH, PUT, REPORT, SEARCH, UNCHECKOUT, UNLOCK, UPDATE, VERSION-CONTROL");
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "useXDomain, withCredentials, Overwrite, Destination, Content-Type, Depth, User-Agent, Translate, Range, Content-Range, Timeout, X-File-Size, X-Requested-With, If-Modified-Since, X-File-Name, Cache-Control, Location, Lock-Token, If");
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "DAV, content-length, Allow");
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "86400");

    }
}
```

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Are you authenticating against one server and then trying to make unauthenticated requests to the other? If that is the case, then it is not a surprise you are getting 401. Nothing to do with CORS.

Comment: I am authenticating on both the servers. and its working properly. My problem is, once the authentication is done, when i request a resource from master, i am getting 401.

Comment: Do I need to send my credentials with requests made after initial authentication? If yes, how do I send it?

Comment: I see your mistake... `withCredentials` is not a header, but XHR option - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http. Without this option cross-origin requests don't contain cookies.

Comment: No... `withCredentials` will enable cookies in general. So your requests will be able to include `JSESSIONID` - thus allowing HTTP session where Spring Security stores information about the authentication. Just add `config.withCredentials = true` instead of setting it as header.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. I have made changes as suggested by you. But I am still getting that error. If I am not wrong, it is sending incorrect jsessionid. Is it because both of my servers are running on localhost i.e same domain? do I need to make any other changes?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67914/discussion-between-pavel-horal-and-sadhvaryu).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are incorrectly setting `withCredentials` as a request header. This is XHR option and should be present directly on the config:

```
config.withCredentials = true;
```

This option will enable cookies for your requests. Your requests will be able to include `JSESSIONID`, thus allowing HTTP session where Spring Security stores information about the authentication.

And as discussed in the chat (see question comments) - be aware that if the two servers are running on the same domain, [they will share cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612177/are-http-cookies-port-specific). That might cause issues (sending incorrect `JSESSIONID`) so you need to access those servers under different host name.