# How read cookies of external site displayed into iframe in javascript

Tags: javascript, iframe, session-cookies

The target of my form submit is an iframe. After, the response is loaded into my iframe, i want to read the cookies especially the jsessionid cookie of external link loaded into my iframe.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: If the httpOnly flag is set, I think it is not possible to read the cookies. You can take a look at https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible because of the "same origin policy". You have to manually send a message (postMessage). See an example here: [Accessing cookies of an iFrame in parent window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30067870/accessing-cookies-of-an-iframe-in-parent-window)

Answer (score 0):

I think that it can help you

```
    $ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.google.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:11.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/11.0');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER ,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER ,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION ,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
$content = curl_exec($ch);

// get cookies
$cookies = array();
preg_match_all('/Set-Cookie:(?<cookie>\s{0,}.*)$/im', $content, $cookies);

print_r($cookies['cookie']);
```

Comment: So, there is another way to display the response of the remote server without using iframe and read the cookies ? if yes, how can i do this?   the following is my form submit form ID="the-form" action="mydomain.com/j_spring_security_check" method="post" target="my_iframe">