# How can I get cookies from an iframe of a specific site using js?

Tags: javascript, ajax, cookies, iframe

I am currently working on a project, which is to create an **iframe** for another page and I want to extract cookies from this page, **but when I declare cookies**, `other values ​​are output`, can anyone help me?

***Methods did't work***
[accessing-cookies-of-an-iframe-in-parent-window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30067870/accessing-cookies-of-an-iframe-in-parent-window)

[how-read-cookies-of-external-site-displayed-into-iframe-in-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34637048/how-read-cookies-of-external-site-displayed-into-iframe-in-javascript)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing cookies of an iFrame in parent window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30067870/accessing-cookies-of-an-iframe-in-parent-window)

Comment: Or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34637048/how-read-cookies-of-external-site-displayed-into-iframe-in-javascript

Comment: If something did not work as expected, please add all attempts to your question by editing it