# Spring SSO authorization fails without context-path

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I followed [this guide](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/#_social_login_authserver) and cloned the [authserver](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-boot-oauth2/tree/master/auth-server). The project has an `authserver` and a `client` (as test). Example works fine but if I remove [context-path](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-boot-oauth2/blob/master/auth-server/src/test/resources/client.yml#L3) property (I just want my app to work on `/`), it fails after redirect back to the `client`. Example:

1. Go to the `client` (`localhost:9999`);
2. Redirected to the `authserver` (`localhost:8080`);
3. Login through GitHub;
4. Redirected to the `authserver` and immediatly to the `client` with next url:

> http://localhost:9999/login?code=dqoxz4&state=79qtJ5

Whitelabel error page responds:

> There was an unexpected error (type=Unauthorized, status=401).
>   Authentication Failed: Could not obtain access token

As I mentioned above, it fails only if `context-path` is `/` (or removed at all). Otherwise, all works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your link:

> The context path has to be explicit if you are running both the client
>   and the auth server on localhost, otherwise the cookie paths clash and
>   the two apps cannot agree on a session identifier.

We run successfully an app on / and AuthServer on /uaa. Try to set Context-Path on your AuthServer. Look at cookies from your app and AuthServer: they should not have same path.

**EDIT:**

Different domains should be fine. They don't share cookies. On same host, like localhost, you must use context path, because cookies are not port specific. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16328399/926620

Alternatively, you put domains in /etc/hosts (linux) or c:\windos\system32\drivers\etc\hosts. Just add line like:

```
127.0.0.1 website authserver
```

And then you can use http://website:9999 and http://authserver:8080 on same machine for development.

Or you can also set different names for cookies. See http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html:

```
server.session.cookie.name=auth
server.session.cookie.name=web
```

Comment: I would like to host auth server on another domain. By the way, I have two `JSESSIONID` on the client. Will it work if I'll try to access auth server with a local IP?

Comment: Thanks! The solution with `hosts` is awesome!

Comment: The different names for server and client cookies did the trick for me. +1

Answer (score 0):

You can set RedirecURI in your client application:

> ```
> security:   oauth2:
> client:
>   client-id: acme
>   client-secret: acmesecret
>   access-token-uri: http://localhost:8080/oauth/token
>   user-authorization-uri: http://localhost:8080/oauth/authorize
>   pre-established-redirect-uri: http://localhost:9999/client
> ```

and you can set it on oauth2 server while registering the clients.

but I think it return to your ROOT context pass, Somthing like it have not enough persmission on Root pass or another application uses this context pass...