# Session authentication with Django channels

Tags: python, django, session, websocket, django-channels

Trying to get authentication working with Django channels with a very simple websockets app that echoes back whatever the user sends over with a prefix `"You said: "`.

My processes:

```
web: gunicorn myproject.wsgi --log-file=- --pythonpath ./myproject
realtime: daphne myproject.asgi:channel_layer --port 9090 --bind 0.0.0.0 -v 2
reatime_worker: python manage.py runworker -v 2
```

I run all processes when testing locally with `heroku local -e .env -p 8080`, but you could also run them all separately.

Note I have WSGI on `localhost:8080` and ASGI on `localhost:9090`.

Routing and consumers:

```
### routing.py ###

from . import consumers

channel_routing = {
    'websocket.connect': consumers.ws_connect,
    'websocket.receive': consumers.ws_receive,
    'websocket.disconnect': consumers.ws_disconnect,
}
```

and

```
### consumers.py ###

import traceback 

from django.http import HttpResponse
from channels.handler import AsgiHandler

from channels import Group
from channels.sessions import channel_session
from channels.auth import channel_session_user, channel_session_user_from_http

from myproject import CustomLogger
logger = CustomLogger(__name__)

@channel_session_user_from_http
def ws_connect(message):
    logger.info("ws_connect: %s" % message.user.email)
    message.reply_channel.send({"accept": True})
    message.channel_session['prefix'] = "You said"
    # message.channel_session['django_user'] = message.user  # tried doing this but it doesn't work...

@channel_session_user_from_http
def ws_receive(message, http_user=True):
    try:
        logger.info("1) User: %s" % message.user)
        logger.info("2) Channel session fields: %s" % message.channel_session.__dict__)
        logger.info("3) Anything at 'django_user' key? => %s" % (
            'django_user' in message.channel_session,))

        user = User.objects.get(pk=message.channel_session['_auth_user_id'])
        logger.info(None, "4) ws_receive: %s" % user.email)

        prefix = message.channel_session['prefix']

        message.reply_channel.send({
            'text' : "%s: %s" % (prefix, message['text']),
        })
    except Exception:
        logger.info("ERROR: %s" % traceback.format_exc())

@channel_session_user_from_http
def ws_disconnect(message):
    logger.info("ws_disconnect: %s" % message.__dict__)
    message.reply_channel.send({
        'text' : "%s" % "Sad to see you go :(",
    })
```

And then to test, I go into Javascript console on the *same* domain as my HTTP site, and type in:

```
> var socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:9090/')
> socket.onmessage = function(e) {console.log(e.data);}
> socket.send("Testing testing 123")
VM481:2 You said: Testing testing 123
```

And my local server log shows:

```
ws_connect: test@test.com

1) User: AnonymousUser
2) Channel session fields: {'_SessionBase__session_key': 'chnb79d91b43c6c9e1ca9a29856e00ab', 'modified': False, '_session_cache': {u'prefix': u'You said', u'_auth_user_hash': u'ca4cf77d8158689b2b6febf569244198b70d5531', u'_auth_user_backend': u'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend', u'_auth_user_id': u'1'}, 'accessed': True, 'model': <class 'django.contrib.sessions.models.Session'>, 'serializer': <class 'django.core.signing.JSONSerializer'>}
3) Anything at 'django_user' key? => False
4) ws_receive: test@test.com
```

Which, of course, makes no sense. Few questions:

1. Why would Django see `message.user` as an `AnonymousUser` but have the actual user id `_auth_user_id=1` (this is my correct user ID) in the session?
2. I am running my local server (WSGI) on 8080 and daphne (ASGI) on 9090 (different ports). And I didn't include `session_key=xxxx` in my WebSocket connection - yet Django was able to read my browser's cookie for the correct user, `test@test.com`? [According to Channels docs, this shouldn't be possible](http://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting-started.html#authentication).
3. Under my setup, what is the best / simplest way to carry out authentication with Django channels?

Answer (score 19):

**Note:** This answer is explicit to `channels 1.x`, `channels 2.x` uses a [different auth mechanism](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/one-to-two.html#http-sessions-and-django-auth).

---

I had a hard time with django channels too, i had to dig into the source code to better understand the docs ...

## Question 1:

The docs mention this kind of long trail of decorators relying on each other (`http_session`, `http_session_user` ...) that you can use to wrap your message consumers, in the middle of that trail it states this:

> Now, one thing to note is that you only get the detailed HTTP information during the connect message of a WebSocket connection (you can read more about that in the ASGI spec) - this means we’re not wasting bandwidth sending the same information over the wire needlessly.
>   This also means we’ll have to grab the user in the connection handler and then store it in the session;....

Its easy to get lost in [all that](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/1.x/getting-started.html#authentication), at least we both did ...

You just have to remember that this happens when you use [`channel_session_user_from_http`](https://github.com/django/channels/blob/08ff57ac9b1d2599e071b62579c4ec64d1b08691/channels/auth.py):

1. It calls `http_session_user`
   a. calls `http_session` which will parse the message and give us a `message.http_session` attribute.
   b. Upon returning from the call, it initiates a `message.user` based on the information it got in `message.http_session` ( this will bite you later)
2. It calls `channel_session` which will initiate a  dummy session in `message.channel_session` and ties it to the message reply channel.
3. Now it calls `transfer_user` which will move the `http_session` into the `channel_session`

This happens during the connection handling of a websocket, so on subsequent messages you won't have acces to detailed HTTP information, so what's happening after the connect is that you're calling `channel_session_user_from_http` again, which in this situation (post-connect messages) calls `http_session_user` which will attempt reading the Http information but fails resulting in [setting `message.http_session` to `None` and overriding `message.user` to `AnonymousUser`](https://github.com/django/channels/blob/08ff57ac9b1d2599e071b62579c4ec64d1b08691/channels/auth.py#L46).
That's why you need to use `channel_session_user` in this case.

## Question 2:

> Channels can use Django sessions either from cookies (if you’re running your websocket server on the same port as your main site, using something like Daphne), or from a session_key GET parameter, which works if you want to keep running your HTTP requests through a WSGI server and offload WebSockets to a second server process on another port.

Remember `http_session`, that decorator that gets us the `message.http_session` data? it appears that if it doesn't find a `session_key` GET parameter it [fails to `settings.SESSION_COOKIE_NAME`](https://github.com/django/channels/blob/9942c59851b76722ac0a8533102a3b886aff688b/channels/sessions.py#L181), which is the regular `sessionid` cookie, so whether you provide `session_key` or not, you'll still get connected if you're logged in, of course that happens only when your ASGI and WSGI servers are on the same domain (127.0.0.1 in this case), [the port difference doesn't matter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16328399/4724196).

I think the difference that the docs are trying to communicate but didn't expand on is that you need to setup `session_key` GET parameter when having your `ASGI` and `WSGI` servers on different domains since cookies are restricted by domain not port.

Due to that lack of explanation i had to test running ASGI and WSGI on same port and different port and the result was the same, i was still getting authenticated, changed one server domain to `127.0.0.2` instead of `127.0.0.1` and the authentication was gone, set the `session_key` get parameter and the authentication was back again.

**Update:** a rectification of the docs paragraph was [just pushed](https://github.com/django/channels/pull/537) to the channels repo, it was meant to mention domain instead of port like i mentioned.

## Question 3:

my answer is the same as turbotux's but longer, you should use `@channel_session_user_from_http` on ws_connect and `@channel_session_user` on ws_receive and ws_disconnect, nothing from what you showed tells that it won't work if you do that change, maybe try removing `http_user=True` from your receive consumer? even thou i suspect it has no effect since its undocumented and intended only to be used by Generic Consumers...

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank a lot, I was buried completely by the source code to understand how to write my tests for consumers. Now I see it clear

Comment: It feels great to be of help!

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem and I found that it was due to a couple of issues that might be the cause. I'm not suggesting this will solve your issue, but might give you some insight. Keep in mind I am using rest framework. First I was overriding the User model. Second when I defined the `application` variable in my root `routing.py` I didn't use my own AuthMiddleware. I was using the docs suggested AuthMiddlewareStack. So, per the [Channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/authentication.html) docs, I defined my own custom authentication middleware, which takes my JWT value from the cookies, authenticates it and assigns it to the `scope["user"]` like so:

**routing.py**

```
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter

import app.routing
from .middleware import JsonTokenAuthMiddleware

application = ProtocolTypeRouter(
    {
        "websocket": JsonTokenAuthMiddleware(
            (URLRouter(app.routing.websocket_urlpatterns))
        )
    }
```

**middleware.py**

```
from http import cookies
from django.contrib.auth.models import AnonymousUser
from django.db import close_old_connections
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from rest_framework_jwt.authentication import BaseJSONWebTokenAuthentication

class JsonWebTokenAuthenticationFromScope(BaseJSONWebTokenAuthentication):

    def get_jwt_value(self, scope):
        try:
            cookie = next(x for x in scope["headers"] if x[0].decode("utf-8") 
                == "cookie")[1].decode("utf-8")
            return cookies.SimpleCookie(cookie)["JWT"].value
        except:
            return None


class JsonTokenAuthMiddleware(BaseJSONWebTokenAuthentication):
    def __init__(self, inner):
        self.inner = inner

    def __call__(self, scope):

        try:
            close_old_connections()
            user, jwt_value = 
                JsonWebTokenAuthenticationFromScope().authenticate(scope)
            scope["user"] = user
        except:
            scope["user"] = AnonymousUser()
        return self.inner(scope)
```

Hope this helps this helps!

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question you need to use the:

```
channel_session_user
```

decorator in the receive and disconnect calls.

```
channel_session_user_from_http
```

calls the transfer_user session during the connect method to transfer the http session to the channel session. This way all future calls may access the channel session to retrieve user information.

To your second question I believe what you are seeing is that default web socket library passes the browser cookies over the connection.

Third, I think your setup will be working quite well once have changed the decorators.

Comment: Tried this - doesn't change anything. I still receive the exact same `AnonymousUser` object.

Comment: Using `@http_session_user` I can get the proper `message.user` object, but then the attribute `message.channel_session` does not exist.