# Angular (4) CSRF different ports on same computer

Tags: spring, angular

I have a small spring boot app which exposes a REST-service with two methods "/upload" (POST) and "/show" (GET)

When I run my angular 2 app on my computer, http://computer.domain.com:4200, and have the spring boot rest-service on the same computer on a different port, http://computer.domain.com:8080, the CSRF-part of angular 2 doesn't wanna send the XSRF-token with the header.

If I deploy the Angular GUI within the spring boot WAR so that both the REST and GUI is accesiable via http://computer.domain.com:8080 everything that's CSRF-related then works.

I thought that Cookies and angular were 'agnostic' when it came to what port they were sent from, as long as it originated from the same server.

Am I missing some piece of config that makes angular send CSRF-headers?

Comment: Do you angular app request your rest service on the 8080 port?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cookies/browsers may be not agnostic from the port. See [this question and the related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612177/are-http-cookies-port-specific).

The common setup is [to configure angular-cli to setup a proxy](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md).

For example if your rest endpoint start with `api`, you should create a `proxy.conf.json`

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://computer.domain.com:8080",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

Then update your `package.json` `start` script to:

```
"start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
```

The frontend should make its http call to `http://computer.domain.com:4200/api...`

Hope it helps

Comment: I'm gonna try to see if this works. I saw someone mention this yesterday on some post on some site, but I thought that there'd be another way.

Comment: I also must add that the cookie that the spring framework dished out was HttpOnly, which didn't exactly help Angular on the way....

If anyone ever reads this, make sure it's not HttpOnly.