# Browser not sending cookie in subsequent request

Tags: python, python-3.x, cookies, web, sanic

Working with a project, where using cookie for user identification.

When user arrives, it calls the service (which is running in localhost) and the service sending cookie with the response header looks like below:

```
curl 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1.0/tracking' -X OPTIONS -H 'Access-Control-Request-Method: POST' -H 'Origin: http://local.com:8080' -H 'Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type,x-forwarded-for' --compressed
```

The response header looks like below:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: 60
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, x-forwarded-for
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, PATCH, GET
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Set-Cookie: id=random_id_123_123; expires=Wed, 06-Dec-2017 10:57:36 GMT; Domain=.local.com; Path=/
```

And then after a specific user action, the app is sending following API request:

```
curl 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1.0/tracking?event=video_added&user_id=123123123' -H 'Origin: http://local.com:8080' -H 'Accept: */*' -H 'Referer: http://local.com:8080/' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' --compressed
```

The request header for the above request looks like below:

```
GET api/v1.0/tracking?event=video_added&user_id=123123123 HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:8000
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: */*
Origin: http://local.com:8080
User-Agent: My user agent
Referer: http://local.com:8080/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
```

I was expecting the cookie (random_id_123_123) to be received with the first request as response header would be the request header for the second request.

The website is running on: http://local.com:8080 (which actually running on local machine and my vhost config pointing 127.0.0.1 local.com) and its being served by python `SimpleHTTPServer`.

The backend service which is setting the cookie is running on port 8000 in localhost also.
Seems I have missed something during the implementation. Whats that?

Edit: Here is the [code](https://codeshare.io/5DVZ4O).

Comment: It'd be really hard for us to tell *if you don't post any code*

Comment: @MatiasCicero I have added the code link.

Answer (score 10):

Your issue is that cookies are only sent based on the domain. Your code has

```
var settings = {
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1.0/tracking?event=video_added&tracking_id=123123123",
  "method": "GET",

}
```

The url is `127.0.0.1:8000` and it should be `local.com:8000` if you want the cookies to be passed.

Comment: Edited the question. The service which is setting the cookie is running on 127.0.0.1:8000 and the website which is calling the API is running on 127.0.0.1:8080.

Comment: See this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612177/are-http-cookies-port-specific. If you are browsing it as `local.com:8080` in browser then the api should also use `local.com:8000` because even if `local.com` is pointing to `127.0.0.1`, they are not same when it comes to cookie sharing

Comment: Also if you want you can even remove `response.cookies["id"]["domain"] = ".local.com"` and that also should help you.

Comment: This is the best answer on the internet right now

Comment: yeah but what about cross origin cookie? I have tried everything without luck... Changed SameSite=None, Secure=true, httonly...etc and I cannot send the cookie. React/NetCoreApi.

Answer (score 2):

Last time I checked, curl doesn't have enabled the cookies by default.

To do so you will need to:

- Use the parameter -b /path/to/cookiejar to read cookies.
- Use the parameter -c /path/to/cookiejar to write cookies.

So your requests should become:

```
curl -c cookiejar 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1.0/tracking' \
-X OPTIONS -H 'Access-Control-Request-Method: POST' \
-H 'Origin: http://local.com:8080' \
-H 'Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type,x-forwarded-for' \
--compressed
```

And:

```
curl -b cookiejar 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1.0/tracking?event=video_added&user_id=123123123' \
 -H 'Origin: http://local.com:8080' \
 -H 'Accept: */*' \
 -H 'Referer: http://local.com:8080/' \
 -H 'Connection: keep-alive' --compressed
```