# why logging into one node application logs me out of another.?

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, passport.js

why logging into one nodejs application logs me out of another?
Both are running on different ports and using passport for authentication and express-session

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you log on in one of your apps you get a cookie that is used to authenticate you with the server.

But Cookies are [defined on hosts,  no ports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612177/are-http-cookies-port-specific), so any cookie you set in any of your apps will rewrite the other one, logging you out of the first app.