# How do I display the Steam OpenID page in a popup window?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, passport.js, openid

On the server side I have implemented a working authentification via passport-steam. When I open the URL `.../api/v1/connect/steam` it redirects me to the Steam Login page and when I succesfully log in, it redirects me back to `returnURL`.

But now I want to connect it with my frontend and this is where I'm a bit lost. To access `.../api/v1/connect/steam` I have to send an authorization header (Firebase Authentification) with `Bearer <token>`. Otherwise I can't access the URL.

Unfortunately I can't send headers when using `window.open`, so I don't know where I should start solving the problem. It comes to my mind that maybe I should do a `GET` request with the authorization header and then return the OpenID URL (`https://steamcommunity.com/openid/login?openid.mode=checkid_setup...`) but I haven't found a way to retrieve the URL.

It seems like there is also no way for me to access `req` inside the `SteamStrategy` callback.

Can someone guide me in the right direction?

Edit: So I found out I actually can access `req` inside the strategy callback but that doesn't seem to help me either, since I need the OpenID URL as response and not get redirected to that URL.

Comment: We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angularjs - Send authorization header in redirection with $window.open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48891267/angularjs-send-authorization-header-in-redirection-with-window-open).