# 2 django apps installed locally are not working properly on same browser, facing login/logout problem

Tags: python, django, session

I am working on 2 Django app which is running on ports - 8001 and 8002.
But the problem is when I click on any link on the second app, the first app make me log out and when I log in to the first one, the second app makes me log out.

Is there any session conflict? Can anyone suggest me how to solve this?

Comment: Why are the two apps on different ports? Why aren't they part of the same project on the same port?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I am working in 2 different projects which may belong to different clients. What's a problem in it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there's a session conflict. Cookies aren't [port-specific](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1612177/1925257), *i.e.*, server running on port A can read and write cookies set by a server running on port B, if both are on the same domain.

Since Django uses the name called `sessionid` for session cookies, both your django apps (I think you meant projects?) are overwriting this cookie.

However, Django allows you to use specific name for the session cookie using [`SESSION_COOKIE_NAME`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#session-cookie-name) setting. So you can change one project's cookie name.

```
SESSION_COOKIE_NAME = 'sessionid_project1'
```

---

And you may also want to rename the csrf cookie using [`CSRF_COOKIE_NAME`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#csrf-cookie-name) setting to avoid conflict there as well.