# Django memcached session get deleted

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Two Django applications(DRF) are running on two separate ports 8001 and 8000 with same host localhost. I am using memcached to store the sessions. Both the application share the sessions from the memcache. when i try to access pages using second application after logining in using first I am getting error :

"**The request's session was deleted before the request completed. The user may have logged out in a concurrent request, for example."**

I want to build a distributed apps where one app can be used for auth running on a separate docker, so other apps can share the session using memcached

Sessionmiddleware is able to populate the session object in the Request object, but after execution of below line of code in AuthenticationMiddleware
**request.user = SimpleLazyObject(lambda: get_user(request))**
The session._session dictionary elements got deleted.

Comment: use token based authentication to `django rest framework`

Comment: @AnjaneyuluBatta Batta  There is constraint that I have to use manage sessions.

Answer (score 0):

In the above case you are running application on two different ports with the same database. If `user1` logged in with port `8000` then a session will be created for him. And again `user1` logged in with port `8001` then the existing session will be replaced/destroyed by the new session. Because browser treats `localhost:8000` and `localhost:8001` as two different domains.

To avoid it you can use `nginx` as a `reverse proxy` server with same ip `127.0.0.1` or domain `localhost`. Now, route the api requests to port `8001` and web requests to port `8000`.

In above case the domain `localhost` remains same so `django` will not replace existing session. So, It will work.

Reference: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/

Comment: localhost is the domain, I also mentioned that I am able to receive the same session id but during authentication the session from memcached  got deleted. https://stackoverflow.com/a/16328311/4520949

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue we need to add the same secret key in the settings in both Django applications.
Django adds the user in the request body in authmiddleware. The user can be anonymous(unauthenticated) or authenticated user. The session is verified before adding the user in the request. This verification is done as follows.

**session_hash_verified = session_hash and constant_time_compare(
                    session_hash,
                    user.get_session_auth_hash()
                )**

This user.get_session_auth_hash() function uses salted_hmac(key_salt, self.password).hexdigest() function for verification. salted_hmac function uses settings.SECRET_KEY for calculating the hash. If both applications secret keys are different then session hasj will not be varified.