# Not being able to maintain php session when in CORS environment

Tags: php, session, cookies, axios

I have a situation that goes like this :
I have a php project that I made from scratch serving as an API endpoint to a client web app created with React. For now they are both locally, php running on `localhost:8000` and react on `localhost:3000`.
The issue appears when I try to make token protected request using axios. The php generated session is lost after login.

I've tried to add `withCredentials:true` client side and also enable 
`header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']);` in the server side as many of the accpeted answers here mentioned but did not have no luck.

PHP headers :

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']);
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Request-With, Set-Cookie, Cookie, Bearer');
```

Axios request:

```
return axios({
    method: 'GET',
    url: LOAD_NOTES_ENDPOINT,
    headers: {'Authorization': token, 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',}
})
.then(response => {
    console.log(response.data);
    return response;
})
.catch(
    (err) => {
        return err.response;
    }
);
```

Currently I'm able to send generate token on login and send it back when trying to access protected route and this works fine if I make the request on Postman and this confirmed that this is strictly a CORS issue. 
I've struggled for 2 days now to find a solution and opened every possible link on the web regarding this issue but all of them are are proposing things I've already tried and didn't work. 
I could find a workaround but that would leave the server open to CSRF attacks and that is something that I have to prevent.

I'm I missing something here? Did anyone else find a solution about this?

Comment: What is the content of $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']? Did you try using "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" in PHP?

Comment: @Sebastian `http://localhost:3000` , and yes I tried with allowing all origins.

Comment: *“confirmed that this is strictly a CORS issue”* How exactly did you confirm that? When things don’t work the way you expect, what is the exact error message the browser is logging in the devtools console?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know what's going wrong there. However I got it running with this little setup:

file 55976696.php

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Request-With, Set-Cookie, Cookie, Bearer');

echo json_encode('php successs');
```

> php -S localhost:8000 55976696.php

file 55976696.js

```
var express = require('express');
const app = express()

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.sendFile('55976696.html', {root: __dirname}))

app.listen(3000, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port 3000!`))
```

file 55976696.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script>
function test() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:8000', {
        withCredentials: false,
    }).then(res => { 
        console.log('SUCCESS', res);
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log('erro', error);
    })
   }; 
</script>
</head>
<body>
test
<div onClick="test()">go</div>
</body>
</html>
```

> node 55976696.js

There is just a little change to your axios.get call and I made sure that the PHP header is what I want ...

Comment: Were you able to access the same session ?  Cause this is where I'm failing. I can't seem to reach the session that is generated in the login route at this route that I'm trying to reach now.

Comment: I did not try that. I think that you have to make sure that the php session id is delivered correctly. Do you transfer it via query? However if you develop an api, I suggest that you do not use php sessions at all, you should prefer a token solution and store the session in the client

Comment: I would also use a sessionless token like JWT or something similar, but that was my challenge. To be able to do the backend without using any libraries at all. I've been using frameworks for a long time and I decided to learn more about PHP by accepting such a challenge. Anyways, thanks for the help and your time. Much appreciated.

Comment: Take a lookt here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612177/are-http-cookies-port-specific