# Response header cookies not set in the browser

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, cookies

I'm building a single page application using Vue.js and Laravel, the response header contains The set-cookie header

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Host: localhost:8000
Date: Fri, 14 Jun 2019 16:59:49 +0000
Connection: close
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.3.4
Set-Cookie: token=test; expires=Fri, 14-Jun-2019 17:59:49 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/; domain=localhost:8080
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Date: Fri, 14 Jun 2019 16:59:49 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8080
Vary: Origin
X-RateLimit-Limit: 60
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 59
```

but the cookies not saved in the browser, The Laravel API works under localhost:8000 and the Vue.js frontend works under localhost:8080.
What's the solution for this problem ?

Comment: `expires=Fri, 14-Jun-2019 17:59:49 GMT` was couple hours ago

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are HTTP cookies port specific?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612177/are-http-cookies-port-specific)

Comment: Yes I know, I just was away from the laptop for a while ...