# cookie is not working for two different urls of react projects due to different urls

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setcookie

I am using [tiny-cookie](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tiny-cookie) for saving language of 2 different projects like, **abc.dev.example.com** and **xyz.dev.example.com** as below

```
setCookie('language', lang)
```

As projects are running on **localhost:3000** and **localhost:8000** in dev environment locally; in the chrome debugger, for cookies domain, as shown, the domain is same i.e. **localhost** see screenshot below (same for localhost:3000)

[image: chrome debugger application for localhost:8000]

Now, When i Switch to **localhost:3000**, I am getting the language as to be **tr** which is intended. But, when I deploy the projects on their domains; the language is saving and showing in chrome application area but domains are different.

How to solve this issue so that it start working. I have also tried to edit the Domain for both urls (I make it .dev.meeraspace.com in chrome application) to be the same and it then start working. I have also tried below code in both projects like

```
setCookie('language', lang, { domain: '.dev.example.com' })
setCookie('language', lang, { domain: '.dev.example.com' })
```

Can anyone face such issue? Please, help. Thanks

Comment: This is not an issue - this is by design. To share the same cookie both apps have to work in the same domain - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612177/are-http-cookies-port-specific  or you need some backend service that will share user settings between domains

Answer (score 0):

I have accomplish this by making both the domain same by below code:

```
const url = new URL(window.location.href)
    if (url.hostname !== 'localhost') {
      const domainParts = url.hostname.split('.')
      domainParts.shift()
      const options = {
        domain: `.${domainParts.join('.')}`
      }
      setCookie('language', lang, options)
    } else {
      setCookie('language', lang)
    }
```

It is now getting and saving same domain i.e. `.dev.example.com`

I hope it can help someone.