# Unique session per domain - NodeJS - Express session

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies, express-session

i'm having an issue where I have 2 frontend applications running on 2 different domains: `localhost:3000` and `localhost:3001`.
They both are communicating with an API running on `localhost:4000`.
The issue that i'm having with the express session is when I connect to `localhost:3000` and make a request to any route from `localhost:3001`, the browser is using the cookie set in `localhost:3000`.

Here is my session configuration:

```
const sessionConfig = {
  store: new MongoStore({
    mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection,
  }),
  cookie: {
    maxAge: THIRTY_MINUTES,
  },
  resave: true,
  rolling: true, // Allows to refresh cookie's max age on every request.
  saveUninitialized: true,
  secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET, // this is a random key
};
```

I tried modifying paths / cookie name when the user authenticates on `localhost:3000` but it doesn't seem to work.

I could add additional information to the session and create a middleware that would verify where the user is coming from but is this a normal behaviour ?

Comment: Yes, [this is normal behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612177/are-http-cookies-port-specific).

Comment: Thanks for the link, To work it out locally I changed `localhost:3001` to`127.0.0.1:3001` and kept the other app on `localhost:3000`