# http response not setting cookie in the browser

Tags: reactjs, django, cookies, django-rest-framework, http-headers

### TLDR:

The following `response` header doesn't set the cookie in browser:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Length: 7
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Tue, 27 Apr 2021 15:58:02 GMT
Referrer-Policy: same-origin
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.9.4
Set-Cookie: csrftoken=r5r2YcZZvJKs79cbLd24VSyNscpUsxJB6UuWiWO2TXriy6B4r8KDZrwSDyI091K1; expires=Tue, 26 Apr 2022 15:58:02 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/; SameSite=Lax
Vary: Accept, Cookie, Origin
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
```

My `request` headers:

```
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Host: 127.0.0.1:8000
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Pragma: no-cache
Referer: http://localhost:3000/
sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="90", "Google Chrome";v="90"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36
```

---

I am new to Django, react and "http header" related stuff.

My django dev server runs at:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/
```

and my react dev server runs at:

```
http://127.0.0.1:3000
```

1. In order to access the website, login is required. So, all unauthorized requests are 1st redirected to login page, by configuring react-router [and following this template](https://usehooks.com/useAuth/). So, till now, no api calls are made.
2. In order to post login data, i need to have csrf token set by the server. But since i have not made any api calls, i created an endpoint `/api/csrf/` explicitly, to set the csrf token.

```py
# URL: /api/csrf/
class CSRFGet(APIView):
    """
    Explicitly set csrf cookie
    """

    @method_decorator(ensure_csrf_cookie)
    def get(self, request):
        return Response('hello')
```

I call this endpoint, when `useProvideAuth` hook is mounted.

```
function useProvideAuth() {
    const [token, setToken] = useState(null);

    const login = (username, password) => {
        return axios.post(
            '/auth/',
            {
                username: username,
                password: password
            })
            .then(response => {
                setToken(response.token) 
            })
    }

    useEffect(()=> {
        axios.get(
            '/csrf/'
        )
    },[])

    return {
        token,
        login,
    }
}
```

3. To retrieve and set this cookie, i followed the [official Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/csrf/#ajax). I also enabled CORS policy using [django-CORS-headers allow all origins](https://github.com/adamchainz/django-cors-headers#cors_allow_all_origins).

Now, when i make a request to any page, it redirects to login page, and i can see `api/csrf/` responds with:

```
Set-Cookie: csrftoken=LgHo2Y7R1BshM4iPisi5qCXhdHyAQK7hD0LxYwESZGcUh3dXwDu03lORdDq02pzG; expires=Tue, 26 Apr 2022 06:29:23 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/; SameSite=Lax
```

But, the cookie is not set at all. Why is it so?

Is my approach for getting csrf cookie correct? Please let me know, if i am making any security vulnerability with this approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the issue was, i was using `http://127.0.0.1:8000` to make api calls, where as my server was on `http://localhost:8000`. Because of this, `host` and `origin`, in my `request` headers didn't match the same domain.

Cookies can be allowed to be used under same domain, with [different ports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612177/are-http-cookies-port-specific) and [subdomains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18492576/share-cookie-between-subdomain-and-domain), unlike [`Same-Origin` policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy), but cannot be used cross-domains.

In my case, I guess `http://127.0.0.1:8000` & `http://localhost:8000` were considered different domains, and thus the browser was not setting my cookie.

**Thanks [Anas Tiour](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4017403/anas-tiour),** for stating about `Allow-Credentials`. I had tried that too, but still had no luck until i found out the actual reason.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try adding the following to the `django-cors-headers` configuration and retry?

> CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

Also, please note that the above configuration would probably not work if you are allowing all origins. See this Mozilla documentation: [Credential is not supported if the CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ is ‘*’](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSNotSupportingCredentials)

If you face such error, I suggest setting:

```
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://127.0.0.1:3000",
]
```

or something fancier like:

```
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGIN_REGEXES = [
       r"^http://127.0.0.1:[0-9]{1,4}$",
]
```

Finally, make sure that you are using a `django-cors-headers` version >= 3.5 since the 2 above configuration had different aliases back then.

Let me know if it works, I am very curious.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your post! Turns out the issue was, i was using `http://127.0.0.1:8000` to make api calls, where as my server was on `http://localhost:8000`. I laughed after realizing this xD.

Comment: ++ for stating about `CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True`, which i completely forgot!