# Cookies don't get sent front-end to back-end

Tags: asp.net-core, cookies

I have my React front-end running on `http://localhost:3000` and ASP.NET Core back-end on `https://localhost:44378`. I don't see cookies in requests though I see them in Chrome:

[image]

Here is some requests headers:

```
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: cross-site
```

I tried to set cookies myself:

```
HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("my1", "cookie.None", new CookieOptions() {
    Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddYears(1), SameSite = SameSiteMode.None, Secure = true,
});
HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("my2", "cookie.Lax", new CookieOptions() {
    Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddYears(1), SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax, Secure = true,
});
HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("my3", "cookie.Strict", new CookieOptions() {
    Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddYears(1),  SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict, Secure = true,
});
```

I see them in Chrome:

```
set-cookie: my1=cookie.None; expires=Sun, 29 May 2022 15:28:59 GMT; path=/; secure; samesite=none
set-cookie: my2=cookie.Lax; expires=Sun, 29 May 2022 15:28:59 GMT; path=/; secure; samesite=lax
set-cookie: my3=cookie.Strict; expires=Sun, 29 May 2022 15:28:59 GMT; path=/; secure; samesite=strict
```

But they don't appear in the table above and don't come to the back-end.

This is how I try reading them:

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    foreach (var p in context.Request.Cookies)
    {
        log.Info($"{p.Key} - {p.Value}");
    }
    log.Info(context.Request.Path);
    await next.Invoke();
});
```

EDIT: changing front-end to https I got

```
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: same-site
```

Still doesn't work though [port should not be an issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16328399/312896). But when I run front-end and back-end in the same process, so no cors is needed it works fine.

Comment: How did you get your cookies in back-end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like my requests were considered CORS so I did two things:

1. On server side I added `.AllowCredentials()` inside my `services.AddCors(...)` call. This adds `access-control-allow-credentials: true` to the response.
2. On the client side I instructed `axios` to include credentials into the request with `axios.get(..., { withCredentials: true })`.
3. Start front-end with `HTTPS=true npm start` to have them both on https.