# Cookie can't be read on correct domain

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm sending a cookie from a server that is received by a client at IP `mattyb.puro.com:3000`. However the cookie does not get set and I receive the following warning if I mouse over the info bubble in the picture below

> This attempt to set a cookie via Set-Cookie header was blocked because its domain attribute was invalid with regards to the current host URL.

[image]

However, looking at the domain attribute on the cookie, `mattyb.puro.com`, matches the current domain and should therefore work fine.

According to this [stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612177/are-http-cookies-port-specific) the port 3000 part shouldn't matter.

I should also note that `mattyb.puro.com` is an alias of `localhost` set in `/etc/hosts` (the hosts file).

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.dev mattyb.puro.com
```

How can I set this incoming cookie correctly?