# ASP.NET Core 8 and Duende Identity Server Authentication Schemes (OpenIdConnect, Cookies, JWT)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, openid-connect, duende-identity-server

I have setup 3 projects in visual studio as follows:

- `WebServer` port 5002 which generates the web client pages
- `APIServer` port 7288 where the web server queries the API endpoints and the database to get data into the views
- `AuthorisationServer` port 5001 where it is used to log the user into the application and authenticate/authorise

`WebServer` uses the cookies and OpenIdConnect authentication schemes.
The configuration of the authentication schemes is done in Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("APIClient", client =>
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.Configuration["WarehouseWebAPIRoot"]);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(HeaderNames.Accept, "application/json");
}).AddUserAccessTokenHandler();

builder.Services.AddHttpClient("IDPClient", client =>
  {
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:5001/");
  });

builder.Services.AddAccessTokenManagement(options =>
  {
    options.Client.Clients.Add("identityserver", new 
  IdentityModel.Client.ClientCredentialsTokenRequest
    {
        Address = "https://localhost:5001/connect/token",
        ClientId = "web",
                    ClientSecret = "secret",
        Scope = "WebAppApi:fullaccess"
    });
   });   

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
 {
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
   })
    .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options => { 
        options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Authentication/AccessDenied";
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
        options.SlidingExpiration = true;
        options.Cookie.MaxAge = options.ExpireTimeSpan;
        options.Cookie.SameSite = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.SameSiteMode.Strict;
    })
    .AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
    {   options.AccessDeniedPath= "/Authentication/AccessDenied";
        options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.Authority = "https://localhost:5001";
      
    options.ClientId = builder.Configuration["Authentication:OpenId:ClientId"];
        options.ClientSecret = builder.Configuration["Authentication:OpenId:ClientSecret"];
        options.ResponseType = "code";
        options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
        options.SaveTokens = true;
        options.Scope.Add("roles");
          options.Scope.Add("profile");
        options.Scope.Add("WebAppApi:fullaccess");
        
        options.ClaimActions.Remove("aud");
        options.ClaimActions.DeleteClaim("sid");
        options.ClaimActions.DeleteClaim("idp");
        
        options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("role", "role");
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new()
        {
           
            NameClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Name,
            RoleClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Role,
           
        };
    });

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    options.AddPolicy("AdminOnly", policy =>
    {
        policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
        policy.RequireClaim("role", "Admin");
        
    })
);
```

`APIServer` uses the JWTBearer authentication scheme:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(o =>
{
    o.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    o.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.SaveToken = true;
        options.Authority = builder.Configuration["Authentication:OpenId:Authority"];
        options.Audience = builder.Configuration["Authentication:OpenId:Audience"];
        options.Configuration?.ClaimsSupported.Add("role");
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new()
        {

            ValidateAudience = false,
            NameClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Name,
            RoleClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Role,
            //ValidTypes = new[] { "at+jwt" }
        };
    });

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    options.AddPolicy("AdminOnly", policy =>
    {
        policy.AuthenticationSchemes.Add(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
        policy.RequireClaim("role", "Admin");
    })
);
```

`AuthorisationServer` uses the cookies and OpenIdConnect authentication schemes. Configuration is done in `Program.cs` and `Config.cs`. I can share these if more details are needed.

The user is not authenticated and the logs from the Duende Identity Server are as follows:

> [23:54:57 Debug] Duende.IdentityServer.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint
> ValidatedAuthorizeRequest
> {"ClientId": "web", "ClientName": null, "RedirectUri": "https://localhost:5002/signin-oidc", "AllowedRedirectUris": ["https://localhost:5002/signin-oidc"], "SubjectId": "anonymous", "ResponseType": "code", "ResponseMode": "form_post", "GrantType": "authorization_code", "RequestedScopes": "openid profile roles WebAppApi:fullaccess", "State": "CfDJ8Pu7Fp24kUpGjM8vsRLlDAbPNrdC_l3Qky59ofw-LCER_PUh03HZdP-Nii7JanPnvqKm-MD7_gdrPqWdZpV6NgIUe66T6MZvJZ3XkisfAaCBsYMKDJG5kji8e1hs-I1xlYy1Oy-_9hxN_X4hlrA9rol24B-GnFKFTMXJBSzSiQuUjr5-kt0f6RjFmUBJ1z48i2R2WqNsvE6SKKn9CoAlNCjrsUa-GKVlR6Yi1t0TxL3HqY4M7IKCVvj4fPOgxqNFpa_tbqEUc6mcaXNsDzIY1hvqHkdhtgzZPY53B57ETAdBXrGQG7uhZJWqIlXJEcxy0_0hvMh0Jgle0MoYSLrEdGEFbu11Q0-FxjUVDq6xYkjhQIKyBHbo-VwYiaBa8aL1hA", "UiLocales": null, "Nonce": "638364596969981993.NTJjNzQzYzMtNDM2Ny00Nzc2LWI0ZDYtZWQ2M2I4MTg0YTgwZWEwODIzMjctMTQ2ZC00MTdlLThkOTMtZWM5MGM5MjUyNDg0", "AuthenticationContextReferenceClasses": null, "DisplayMode": null, "PromptMode": "", "MaxAge": null, "LoginHint": null, "SessionId": "", "Raw": {"client_id": "web", "redirect_uri": "https://localhost:5002/signin-oidc", "response_type": "code", "scope": "openid profile roles WebAppApi:fullaccess", "code_challenge": "5m7NDLdV1So0go6tHUS7pI6EFnlxp5Py71xdXkRmObk", "code_challenge_method": "S256", "response_mode": "form_post", "nonce": "638364596969981993.NTJjNzQzYzMtNDM2Ny00Nzc2LWI0ZDYtZWQ2M2I4MTg0YTgwZWEwODIzMjctMTQ2ZC00MTdlLThkOTMtZWM5MGM5MjUyNDg0", "state": "CfDJ8Pu7Fp24kUpGjM8vsRLlDAbPNrdC_l3Qky59ofw-LCER_PUh03HZdP-Nii7JanPnvqKm-MD7_gdrPqWdZpV6NgIUe66T6MZvJZ3XkisfAaCBsYMKDJG5kji8e1hs-I1xlYy1Oy-_9hxN_X4hlrA9rol24B-GnFKFTMXJBSzSiQuUjr5-kt0f6RjFmUBJ1z48i2R2WqNsvE6SKKn9CoAlNCjrsUa-GKVlR6Yi1t0TxL3HqY4M7IKCVvj4fPOgxqNFpa_tbqEUc6mcaXNsDzIY1hvqHkdhtgzZPY53B57ETAdBXrGQG7uhZJWqIlXJEcxy0_0hvMh0Jgle0MoYSLrEdGEFbu11Q0-FxjUVDq6xYkjhQIKyBHbo-VwYiaBa8aL1hA", "x-client-SKU": "ID_NET8_0", "x-client-ver": "7.0.3.0"}, "$type": "AuthorizeRequestValidationLog"}
> 23:54:57 Information] Duende.IdentityServer.ResponseHandling.AuthorizeInteractionResponseGenerator
> Showing login: User is not authenticated

> [23:54:57 Information] Serilog.AspNetCore.RequestLoggingMiddleware
> HTTP GET /connect/authorize responded 302 in 41.8403 ms

> [23:54:57 Information] >Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler
> Cookies was not authenticated. Failure message: Unprotect ticket failed

> [23:54:57 Information] >Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler
> Cookies was not authenticated. Failure message: Unprotect ticket failed

> [23:54:57 Information] >Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler
> Cookies was not authenticated. Failure message: Unprotect ticket failed

> [23:54:57 Information] >Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler
> Cookies was not authenticated. Failure message: Unprotect ticket failed

> [23:54:57 Debug] Duende.IdentityServer.Validation.AuthorizeRequestValidator
> Start authorize request protocol validation

> [23:54:57 Debug] Duende.IdentityServer.Stores.ValidatingClientStore
> client configuration validation for client web succeeded.

> [23:54:57 Debug] Duende.IdentityServer.Validation.AuthorizeRequestValidator
> Checking for PKCE parameters

> [23:54:57 Debug] Duende.IdentityServer.Validation.AuthorizeRequestValidator
> Calling into custom validator: >Duende.IdentityServer.Validation.DefaultCustomAuthorizeRequestValidator

> [23:54:57 Information] Serilog.AspNetCore.RequestLoggingMiddleware
> HTTP GET /Account/Login responded 200 in 23.9251 ms

Could you please let me know why the user does  not get authenticated?
I have tried changing the options to the authentication schemes but with no success. I am following the instructions found in the documentation here: https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v6/quickstarts/

Could you please let me know what I am missing?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get this error:

*>Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler Cookies was not authenticated. Failure message: Unprotect ticket failed*

That means that the the instance can't "decrypt" the received cookie. The cookies are protected using the Data Protection API. See my blog post here about how the cookies are protected:

[Exploring what is inside the ASP.NET Core cookies](https://ftonbladet.se/)

Another cause of trouble can be that the services are using cookies with the same name.

Cookies are shared across all services on the same "domain", meaning that it could be that a service of yours might receive a cookie from another service.

So, ensure that all the cookies in your application is unique per service.

See this answer: [Are HTTP cookies port specific?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612177/are-http-cookies-port-specific)

Third issue is here:

```
.AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options => { 
    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Authentication/AccessDenied";
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
    options.Cookie.MaxAge = options.ExpireTimeSpan;
    options.Cookie.SameSite = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.SameSiteMode.Strict;
})
```

The browser might reject the strict cookie because it was "triggered" by another site, you might need to change to samesitemode.lax.

See my blog post here: [Debugging cookie problems in ASP.NET Core](https://nestenius.se/2023/10/09/debugging-cookie-problems/)

Comment: thank you for the prompt feedback. I am making all the changes you have suggested. But I have an additional question please if you do not mind:  are you suggesting I should add a second hostname for the 127.0.0.1 address so that each server can have its own cookies? Then does this mean that I should install an SSL certificate for that second hostname too? Because now I get the error **AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid** with the setup mentioned above. Thank you for your time and advice.

Comment: no, I mean you can just change the names of the cookie for each service (inside AddCookie..

Comment: another useful domain is https://readme.localtest.me/

Comment: Thank you Tore, all the changes have been made. I also added the CallApi method as described here: https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v6/quickstarts/3_api_access/. This is necessary to get the access_token from the IDP and use it in the APIClient. Everything works now!!!